# XSL apply-templates output issues

Tags: xslt, apply-templates

**Given this XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" ?>
    <products>
        <p>
            <id> 50 </id>
            <name> Murphy </name>
            <price> 33 </price>
        </p>
        <p>
            <id> 40 </id>
            <name> Eddie </name>
            <price> 9999 </price>
        </p>
        <p>
            <id> 20 </id>
            <name> Honey </name>
            <price> 9999 </price>
        </p>
        <p>
            <id> 30 </id>
            <name> Koney </name>
            <price> 11 </price>
        </p>
        <p>
            <id> 10 </id>
            <name> Margarethe </name>
            <price> 11 </price>
        </p>
    </products>
```

---

**With this XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="p[id &gt; 20]">
    <idKP>   <xsl:value-of select="id"/></idKP>
    <skitter><xsl:value-of select="name"/></skitter>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Having this output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<idKP>50</idKP><skitter>Murphy</skitter>
<idKP>40</idKP><skitter>Eddie</skitter>
20
Honey
9999
<idKP>30</idKP><skitter>Koney</skitter>
10
Margarethe
11
```

> **Q : Why there are values of those who did not matched? `20, Honey, 9999, ...`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) - when there are no explicit templates to match a particular node, the built-in rules are used, which for element nodes means `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and for text nodes means `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.  The effect of these two rules in combination is to output all the text under the elements but not the element tags themselves.

You could add a second do-nothing template

```
<xsl:template match="p" />
```

to completely ignore `p` elements that don't match your condition.  An explicit template, even a do-nothing one, is preferred over the default built-in rule.

Comment: If you could elaborate more about `explicit templates` I would be very grateful.

Comment: All I mean by "explicit" is an `xsl:template` you have written in your stylesheet, as opposed to the "implicit" built-in rules.

Answer (score 0):

**To add to the answer, this is the solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="p[id &gt; 20]">
    <idKP>   <xsl:value-of select="id"/></idKP>
    <skitter><xsl:value-of select="name"/></skitter>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```