# XML/XSL output showing extra information

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xsl and xml code.

I am seeing the date `2013.08.20` everytime I run it right at the top and I want to know how to remove it from the output.

**XSL stylesheet:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:zs="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="zs:version">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="zs:numberOfRecords">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="zs:recordPosition">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="zs:record">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="zs:recordSchema">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="zs:recordPacking">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="leader">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="controlfield">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datafield[@tag=245]">
        <tr><td>Name: </td><td><b>
            <xsl:for-each select="subfield[@code='a']">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>,&#160;</xsl:for-each></b>
            <xsl:for-each select="subfield[@code='r']">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>,&#160;</xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="subfield[@code='g']">
                (<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>),&#160;</xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="subfield[@code='d']">
                d. <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>&#160;</xsl:for-each>
        </td></tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datafield[@tag=856]">
        <tr><td>Links: </td><td>
            <xsl:element name="a">
               <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='u']"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='y']"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </td></tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="datafield[@tag=857]">
        <tr><td>Image: </td><td>
            <xsl:element name="img">
               <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='u']"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='y']"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:attribute name="width">
                <xsl:text>200</xsl:text>
               </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
                <xsl:value-of select="subfield[@code='y']"/>
        </td></tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML input:**

```
<zs:searchRetrieveResponse xmlns:zs="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
  <zs:version>2013.08.20</zs:version>
  <zs:numberOfRecords>1</zs:numberOfRecords>
  <zs:resultSetId>5031057_1</zs:resultSetId>
  <zs:records>
    <zs:record format="WWI" type="Bibliographic">
      <zs:recordSchema>info:marcXchange</zs:recordSchema>
      <zs:recordPacking>xml</zs:recordPacking>
      <zs:recordData>
        <leader>01136nam 2200301 4500</leader>
        <controlfield tag="001">3/1</controlfield>
        <controlfield tag="003">CaONF</controlfield>
        <controlfield tag="008">150320s2015 onc 00011 eng d</controlfield>
        <controlfield tag="009">NAME</controlfield>
        <datafield tag="245">
          <subfield code="a">Farebrother, George A.</subfield>
          <subfield code="r">Sergeant</subfield>
          <subfield code="g">NiagaraFalls</subfield>
          <subfield code="d">May 26, 1918</subfield>
          <subfield code="u">
            No.2 District Depot. 3rd Bde., Canadian Field Artillery
          </subfield>
          <subfield code="k">1</subfield>
          <subfield code="p">
            NIAGARA FALLS (FAIRVIEW) CEMETERY Ontario,Canada, Family. Sec. M. Lot 76.
          </subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="856">
          <subfield code="y">Test complex URL</subfield>
          <subfield code="2">http://</subfield>
          <subfield code="a">www.nflibrary.ca/test/test.aspx?id=</subfield>
          <subfield code="b">farebrother</subfield>
          <subfield code="c">Display=34</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="856">
          <subfield code="y">Canadian Virtual War Memorial</subfield>
          <subfield code="u">
            http://www.veterans.gc.ca/eng/collections/virtualmem/Detail/425501
          </subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="856">
          <subfield code="y">War Graves Commission</subfield>
          <subfield code="u">
            http://www.cwgc.org/find-war-dead/casualty/425501/FAREBROTHER, GEORGE ALFRED
          </subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="856">
          <subfield code="y">Book of Remembrance</subfield>
          <subfield code="u">
            http://www.veterans.gc.ca/images/collections/books/bww1/ww1405.jpg
          </subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="856">
          <subfield code="y">National Archives</subfield>
          <subfield code="u">

          </subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="856">
          <subfield code="y">Attestation Papers</subfield>
          <subfield code="u">
          </subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="857">
          <subfield code="y">
          </subfield>
          <subfield code="t">
          </subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="857">
          <subfield code="u">
          </subfield>
        </datafield>
      </zs:recordData>
      <zs:recordPosition>1</zs:recordPosition>
    </zs:record>
  </zs:records>
</zs:searchRetrieveResponse>
```

Comment: The result you claim is **not** the result obtained when running the code you have provided. The actual result is a blank document. -- it would be helpful if you posted the result that you expect to get. -- Indenting your XSLT code to make it readable would be a nice addition, too.

Comment: Now we have twice the input and no XSLT. And still no expected output.

Comment: To make a long story short, see this answer posted only an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30764820/3016153

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet seems to have several issues

- most of your templates **do nothing**; this is not wrong per se, but it's a problem when it prevents other templates from being executed; in particular, your template for `"*"` (which is applied to the document element `zs:searchRetrieveResponse`) does nothing, and the processing just ends here, without any output being produced; if what you really mean is "print nothing and keep processing the content of this element" you should use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` inside that template (or, even better, eliminate that template, and the [built-in one](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) will be used instead)
- another template matches `"zs"` (= elements whose *name* is `zs`); if you want it to apply to elements in the `zs` *namespace* you should use `<xsl:template match="zs:*">` (hint: as this template does nothing, and the document element is in the `zs` namespace, remove this template or you will get no output)
- the template matching `"recordData"`, which in theory could do something, is not really executed as the `recordData` element in your input is in the `zs` namespace, so the `match` attribute should be `"zs:recordData"`
- you use `<xsl:output method="html"/>` but you are not producing HTML elements; in fact, your templates (should they be executed) only produce text: you should probably use `<xsl:output method="text"/>`

As you gave no example of the expected output, it's impossible to give you more precise advice.

Comment: Actually, what is need here is *more* templates that do nothing. Or less liberal applying of templates.

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k I added a bunch of templates that do nothing and it fixed the error!